# "If-else" statement going down the wrong section in step debug

Tags: android, if-statement, breakpoints

Hopefully a simple answer but I'm a little baffled. I'm expecting the code to go down the first `if` section below, but it always goes to the `else`.

When I get to line on a breakpoint >> `if (url2!=null && !url2.isEmpty())`
In the expressions window:

- `url2` IS "???/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/toonieJune10_091-640x334.jpg"
- `url2!=null` IS true
- `!url2.isEmpty()` IS true

However when debugging it always seems to hit the else, even though both conditions are true. I'm suspecting something is out of sync with my built code somehow as the step through debugging seems to give me inconsistencies.

I've tried cleaning the code and making some changes in the class and recompiling etc.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

---

```
public String getImageBannerUrl()
{
    if (getPhotoFile1()!=null) return getPhotoFile1().getUrl();
    String url2 = getRemoteImageUrl();

    if (url2!=null && !url2.isEmpty())
    {
        return url2;
    }
    else
    {
        //Otherwise get default image based on category
        return getImageCategoryUrl();
    }       
}
```

Comment: before the if-else statement check fro url2 value,i think you are not getting value via the method getRemoteImageUrl()

Comment: Add `Log.i("SOMETAG", "url2 = " + url2);"` before the second `if-block` and check the LogCat.

Comment: When you step out from the method, what's the return value? I'm thinking that the conditional works but the debugger jumps to the end of method frame (the last `}`) when hitting `return` and that confuses you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - everything actually looks correct in Log.i(), so it must be the debugging going crazy. Stepping through the code hits the last 'return' line. The log.i says otherwise. I'm not sure what would cause the debugger to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like..

```
        public String getImageBannerUrl()
        {
            if ((!getPhotoFile1().isEmpty()) && (!getPhotoFile1().matches(" "))) return getPhotoFile1().getUrl();
            String url2 = getRemoteImageUrl();
            if ((!url2.isEmpty()) && (!url2.matches(" ")))
            {
                return url2;
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise get default image based on category
                return getImageCategoryUrl();
            }

        }
```

Note : here getPhotoFile1() must be returning String value..